# C - Using file as database

Tags: c, database, file, scanf

i'm using VS2013
i have structure like :

```
typedef struct  StuInformation
{
    char studentNumber[100];
    char name[50];
    char sex[10];
    unsigned  short age;
    char m_status[10];
} student;
```

i want to get the information from user one by one :

```
student std;
int RecordSize;
printf("pls insert the student number :\n");
scanf_s("%[^\n]",std.studentNumber);

printf("name : \n");
scanf_s("%[^\n]", std.name);

printf("sex : \n");
scanf_s("%[^\n]", std.sex);

printf("major : \n");
scanf_s("%[^\n]", std.major);

printf("age : \n");
scanf_s("%d", &std.age);

FILE *f;
fopen_s(&f, "student.txt", "a");
RecordSize = sizeof(std);


fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
fwrite(&std, RecordSize, 1, f);
fclose(f);
```

but it seems there is problem in my **scanf_s** the error s : 
**access violation executing location** 
i changed it to

```
scanf_s("%[s^\n]", std.email);
```

because somewhere it's written that scanf_s must contain %s ...

there is another question : how can i read specific record from file and store it as Structure and print it out to user like :

```
printf("student name is : %s ",std.name)
```

Comment: Read file line by line is very slow, should read whole file into memory (once or segment by segment). then parse lines in memory.

Comment: You need the `%s` not because of some incantation, but because that's the proper format designator for a string, which is what you're attempting to read. So did using the correct format designator get rid of the access violation? You didn't say... And to read a specific structure from the file, you can use `fseek` to move the file pointer to where you want if your records remain fixed length. Just move `n * sizeof(struct StuInformation)` if you wrote them out that way, where `n` is the record number you want to read.

Comment: You might be interested in [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the format string in `scanf_s` contains `%s` or `%S`, the function expects another parameter that indicates the size of the string. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx.

Instead of

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]",std.studentNumber);
```

you'll need to use:

```
scanf_s("%[^\n]",std.studentNumber, sizeof(std.studentNumber));
```

Similar changes need to be to the other calls to the function.